# Unable to add kisak-mesa PPA following the command on Launchpad

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, launchpad, mesa

I am trying to add the [kisak-mesa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa) PPA to my system. I usually add PPAs by following the instructions on Launchpad. For this PPA, the instructions look like this:

[image: Launchpad adding this PPA instructions]

However, when I run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa` exactly as instructed, it says "The user named '~kisak' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/kisak-mesa'" but then proceeds to tell me there is a PPA named `kisak-mesa`, which is exactly what I requested in the command.

[image: PPA failing to be added]

What am I doing wrong? How can I install this PPA? Why are the instructions on Launchpad not working? Why is `add-apt-repository` implicitly adding `ubuntu/`?

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on x86_64.

Comment: Sorry, I should've included that information. It's Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64.